# Program to convert DER encoded ASN.1 DN to ASCII String format and vice versa

Tags: openssl

Is there any API/C program to convert DER encoded ASN.1 DN to ASCII String format and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenSSL function `d2i_X509_NAME` will convert an ASN.1 DN to an X509_NAME C structure. The function `i2d_X509_NAME` does the opposite. See:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/i2d_X509.html

There are a few different functions to convert an X509_NAME structure into something human readable. See the functions described on this page for details:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/X509_NAME_print.html